# django-pipeline not working at all

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-pipeline, django-1.7

I were fighting with this for for hours, please, help me fix this or kill me =(

I am getting 404 for all 4 files in view. No compiled files anywhere.

Python 3.4.0 in virtualenv, Django 1.7 RC3.

Btw:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

copies everything from assets to assets_compressed,and adds admin styles there. But there's an error in the end:

```
ValueError: The joined path (/) is located outside of the base path component (/home/val/Programming/Django/nedviga/nedviga/assets)
```

Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pipeline',
)
```

...

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets_compressed')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)
```

...

```
PIPELINE_ENABLED = True

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'

PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'

PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
    'pipeline.compilers.less.LessCompiler'
)

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'libs': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/libs.css'
    },
    'site': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'main.less'
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/main.css'
    }
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'libs': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'
            'libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/libs.js'
    },
    'site': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'main.js'
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/main.js'
    }
}
```

Dir structure:

```
project_name

    assets
        libs
            ...
        main.js
        main.less

    assets_compressed
        *empty*

    project_name
    manage.py
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AAARGH</title>

    {% load compressed %}
    {% compressed_css 'libs' %}
    {% compressed_css 'site' %}
</head>

<body>

    {% compressed_js 'libs' %}
    {% compressed_js 'site' %}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just tried with Django 1.6.6
Results are same. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Is it solved now ? If not, first add   'compressor' to installed apps, and can you try with changing STATICROOT to be outside project ? What is the output now

Answer (score 2):

You need to put comma after each source_filenames. Even if it has only 1 source.

For example:

`'source_filenames': (
    'main.less' ,
 ),`

not

`'source_filenames': (
    'main.less'
 ),`

Comment: Good catch there. Wonder why noone spotted it sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still can be useful but you simply forgot to add 'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder' to your STATICFILES_FINDERS :

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)
```